# How to use Many to Many widget presented in Admin page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I want to use the widget presented in Admin page for Group creation in my Modelform (picture below) but I'm failing in do that.
[image: group-permission-widget]

Does anyone know how can I use a widget like this in my form?

I have two models that have a many-to-many relationship.

I have also created a ModelForm class to get all **first_model** objects that are related to my **second_model**.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your field in the `ModelForm` as a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield)) which will hide most of the implementation details and output the exact same result.

Here is an example of an actual implementation I've made in the past

```
class InterestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Interest.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Interest
        fields = ["name"]
```

---

Alternatively, if you want more control over how it's rendered, you can write the html yourself. Make sure to include the `multiple` property in the `select` tag:

```
    <label for="{{ form.my_m2m_field.auto_id }}">{{ form.my_m2m_field.name }}</label>
    <select name="{{ form.my_m2m_field.html_name }}" id="{{ form.my_m2m_field.auto_id }}" multiple>
        {% for item in form.my_m2m_field.field.queryset %}
            <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{ item.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```